# Is there a way to permanently delete objects in S3 using the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

rm merely adds delete markers, but I want to permanently delete. Is this possible in the AWS CLI?

Answer (score 0):

The following command deletes an object named test.txt from a bucket named my-bucket:

```
aws s3api delete-object --bucket my-bucket --key test.txt
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object.html

Comment: This does not delete the delete marker.